# Display .png file name as the text in the image corner

Tags: timelapse, filenames, time

I have a bunch of images with various filenames (mainly date and time). I want to create the timelapse, where the filename will be visible somewhere in the corner (or at least one of the element-time).

[image]

[image]

Is it any OpenSource software, which could do it for me?
Or preferably how can I do it in i.e. Python code?

Comment: Do you mean to simply display the file name while displaying the image? Or to actually modify the image so that it contains the file name drawn over the image content? Many image viewers have options to do the former, while the latter can be done via command line with e.g. ImageMagick (and probably others), or via GUI with pretty much any image editor...

Comment: Could you perhaps indicate what you've looked in so far in terms of solutions? Anything you tried? Anything that failed for some reason? It would really help answerers as then they can take you're attempts into account when writing an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to overlay date and time onto the corner of photos?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/16953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not insist very much for opensource and you will agree with free software you can use [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/).

- Open in Browser mode
- Select images
- Ctrl+U (batch convert)
- For action select Image->Text
  [image]
- Enter in the field `{Filename}` or select it clicking on right arrow

[image]

- Set output parameters (if required) and press Convert

Comment: Yes, it works! Is there any chance to modify this filename? Remove some strings from there?

Comment: @MKR, I am afraid you can't remove or modify. You can only add info. Check submenus, you will find a lot of options there.

Comment: @MKR, if you want to have only time you can add something like: `{Creation Date [H-M-S]}`, this is hour, minutes, seconds of image creation (get from meta info, not filename)